# What delimiter should I use instead of a , so that excel would recognize it as a new column

Tags: excel, csv

I'm wondering if I can manually do a search replace on my `,`s in my csv generator so that the file when named *.xls would open natively in Excel.

I'm guessing that they just use a different delimiter?

[EDIT] If I leave the `,` alone excel will open the file and treat the ,s as strings to draw, so EVERYTHING winds up in Column A with the commas in place.

In other words

abc, def, ghi

which I want to turn up as

```
A   |  B   |   C
abc | def  |  ghi
```

instead gets drawn as

```
A            |    B    | C
abc, def, ghi|         |
```

Comment: What do you mean by "natively" ? An xls is a binary file format, not plain text.  You may be able to get Excel to parse a text file with an xls extension if you format your data as an HTML table, but you'll still get a warning about the content not being as expected based on the extension.

Comment: Meaning it would allow me to double click on the file and Excel would open it with the values seperated out into separate columns. Currently it just puts everything in column A with the commas as part of the values.

Comment: @KenWhite, hmm... that's a shame. Ok, thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `.xls` file is a binary format, not just a `.csv` file with a different delimiter. (Open one with a hex viewer to see the difference.) The `.xls` file format is documented in [Microsoft Office Excel 97 - 2007 Binary File Format Specification (*.xls 97-2007 format)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/B/E/0BE8BDD7-E5E8-422A-ABFD-4342ED7AD886/Excel97-2007BinaryFileFormat%28xls%29Specification.xps) - note this is a download link to a `.xps` file, not an HTML page.

`.xlsx` are XML-based files, but they're still much more than just "differently delimited CSV files".

If you want Excel to open your file as a CSV file when you double-click it, give it a `.csv` extension and associate Excel with `.csv` files (if it isn't already).

Comment: How can we generate ans .xls file via php or asp?

Comment: @RNKushwaha: That has nothing to do with the question asked here. If you have a new question, first search this site to see if it's been answered before. If it has not, then post your own new question.

Answer (score -3):

Not sure why the above is marked as correct, as it wasn't your question.
The question was how to change the delimiter and not the file ext.
Here's the real answer. 
You're not far off, and it's very easy to do. Click the "A" (The column, but click the actual letter to highlight just the first column ** ONLY ONE COLUMN OR IT WONT WORK **)
Click the Data tab. Click "Text to Columns" (Top Middle)
from here you can change the delimiter to whatever you choose, only have one selected if you only want to use one. You can change it to "K" if you wanted to, and excel will split your text based on the letter K. 
Hope this helps,
Monster

Comment: Welcome. In fact, this question is about how to format csv files so excel can open them without the user having to do the steps you detail here.